# Where to download Juniper Network Connect 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn, juniper

I have a client that needs to connect to his VPN. 
He uses Juniper Network connect though he currently doesnt have it installed.

I want to install it for him but I unable to download from [Junipers download page](http://www.juniper.net/support/products/sa/7.0/#sw)
as I need an account and I don't see an obvious way to register.

Where else can I download this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sometimes the sysadmin hosts the VPN software on the same domain as the VPN login.

So using example.com, you could try:

example.com/*dana-cached/setup/JuniperSetupSP1.cab* for the SP1 file. Possibly by logging on to the VPN site in the browser, they might even link to the download.

As TheGingerDog points out in the comments, if you're on a Mac, using apps downloaded from outside the App Store in OSX now requires that you set OSX to 'Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere' for it to run.

Comment: You'll need to set OSX to 'Allow apps downloaded from: Anywhere' for it to work. 
Alternative URL: http://www.tcnj.edu/~nts/downloads/NetworkConnect/v74R2/

Answer (score 2):

For someone, who is looking for Windows-64 bit, you can download it here [Windows 7 64bit](http://wheatoncollege.edu/technology/started/networks-wheaton/juniper-vpn-instructions/juniper-vpn-instructions-for-windows/)

Comment: was looking for this exactly, I came across the same link before, but I couldn't trust it. Thanks for mentioning

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is a commercial product you have to purchase before you download it

Comment: Technically you're right, it is a commercial product. But the client itself isn't purchased. It's the VPN Appliance hardware with a support contract that is purchased by the company and your client's company should provide him with the software, or a link to download it like in my answer.